# Two client applications on same database.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, tingodb

I am working with BeagleBone. I need to have two services. One is simple web application to make configuration (call i an A) , and other is application that use that configuration (call it a B).

So the problem is when I connect to TingoDB over mongoose/tungus with both applications at the same time. If I am connected at the same time and add something to database from A application, I can see the change in file, but the B application that uses that database cant see that change. I don't know why because every time I need to read from database, in B application, I connect all over again, read, and then disconnect.

When I restart B application it's working fine, and uses the "newest" data. Is there any way to see these changes or read directly from file.

Answer (score 1):

From the [source](https://github.com/sergeyksv/tingodb/) it appears that the file is only read from on collection init, until you close it and init it again. This is far from ideal for multiple services accessing concurrently. Further, I don't see any code that would support concurrent access from multiple processes.

Since Tingo purports to be a clone of Mongo with respect to API, and your use case exceeds what it appears Tingo was designed to accommodate, I would suggest migrating your project to use MongoDB instead.

Comment: But this is running on the BeagleBone Black with 512MB RAM. I dont think it's enough to run DBengine

Comment: Any reason you couldn't provide the "two services" from one nodejs app then?